# Proving not Cauchy by definition

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

I am preparing for my Real Analysis test and I am trying to solve the following:

**Prove that $\left((-1)^{n}\right)$ is not Cauchy directly by the definition**

**What have I tried so far?** I started by negating the Cauchy sequence definition and got the following:

There exists $\epsilon_{0} > 0$ such that for every $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $n,m \geq n_{0}$ such that $\left|x_{n}-x_{m}\right| \geq \varepsilon_{0}$

Having done that, I did the following:

Choose $\epsilon_{0} = 2$. Now, given $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$, choose n even such that $n > n_{0}$ and $m = n + 1 > n_{0} + 1 > n_{0}$

Now, we see that $\left|x_{n}-x_{m}\right| = \left|1-(-1)\right| = 2 = \epsilon_{0}$

Does it look good? Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\epsilon_{0} = 2$ is not a helpful choice for this proof.  Try something smaller

Comment: To elaborate on what @Henry said note that $|x_n-x_m|$ is exactly zero or two. Since they're always within $2$ you'll need a smaller $\epsilon_0$.

Comment: But the negation says that $\left|x_{n}-x_{m}\right| \geq \varepsilon_{0}$. In particular, $\left|x_{n}-x_{m}\right| = \varepsilon_{0}$ should work. Why not?

Comment: Furthermore, how can $\left|x_{n}-x_{m}\right| = 0$ by choosing n even and m odd?

Comment: Perhaps I should have said your proof works but could be more enlightening with a smaller $\epsilon_0$.  By choosing $2$ you are forcing the reader to understand the distinction between $>$ and $\ge$.  If you had chosen something smaller  like $0.1$ then you would have $|x_n-x_{n+1}|=2 > 0.1$ so there is always a gap bigger than $\epsilon_0$ and so there cannot be Cauchy convergence

Comment: @Henry Agree 100%. I am going to pay closer attention from now on!

Comment: But now i am a little confused. Can $\left|x_{n}-x_{m}\right|=0$ by choosing $\mathrm{n}$ even and $\mathrm{m}$ odd?

Comment: Do you know that all Cauchy-sequences are convergent?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe ... on the real numbers

Comment: @Henry Of course.  Knowing that the given sequence can't be Cauchy due to its divergence.